# Is it possible to have a default width that is larger than the min-width?

Tags: css, size, textarea

I have a text area with a certain default width. I want users to be able to scale it down if they think the default width is too big, but the width seems to be acting like a min-width; once I load the web page, I can't make the textarea any smaller than the default width. How can I set it up so the textarea can scale smaller?

http://jsfiddle.net/4mS3m/

My current css:

```
#text-area {
    min-width: 10px;
    min-height: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

The textarea won't scale any smaller than 300x100px.

Comment: width: 100% maybe? max-width: 300px?

Comment: It works in FireFox.  Not at all in Chrome. It must be a browser specific problem.